# Finding week number by passing two timestamps as parameter in Java

Tags: java, mysql

My function should take start timestamp, end timestamp and entered date. Here, start and end timestamps could be anything (any timestamp).

This start timestamp and end timestamp will be of three week. If entered date falls in those timestamp range I need to get week of that date.

```
example:

   start date - 06/08/2011 00:00:00  
   end Date -  26/08/2011  00:00:00
  if entered date -  10/08/2011 This should return week number as 1
   if entered date -  27/08/2011 This should return week number as 3.it has to take count of 7 days,from entered date and give the count of week.
```

Below is my code used.

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class LocaleTimeSample {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            String dt = "";
            String dt1 = "";
            String dt2 = "";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            sdf.setLenient(false);
            String givenDateString = "02/06/2016";// given
            String startDateString = "01/06/2016";// start
            String endDateString = "21/06/2016";// end
            Date givenDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
            Date startDate = sdf.parse(startDateString);
            Date endDate = sdf.parse(endDateString);

            try {
                c.setTime(sdf.parse(startDateString));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());

            System.out.println("1 Week Date : " + dt);
            Date date1 = (Date) sdf.parse(dt);

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            dt1 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("2 Week Date : " + dt1);
            Date date2 = (Date) sdf.parse(dt1);

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // number of days to add
            dt2 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            System.out.println("2 Week Date : " + dt2);
            Date date3 = (Date) sdf.parse(dt2);

            if (givenDate.compareTo(date1) <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Week 1");
            } else if (givenDate.compareTo(date2) <= 0
                    && givenDate.compareTo(date1) > 0) {
                System.out.println("Week 2");
            } else if (givenDate.compareTo(date3) <= 0
                    && givenDate.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
                System.out.println("Week 3");
            }

        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to minimixe the code of line and reusability apprach where were needed.

Any idea regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: `ChronoUnit.WEEK.between(start, entered)`? Other than that, what did _you_ try?

Comment: Idea: start coding. Stackoverflow is **not** a service where you drop requirements and others do the work for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user doesn't show any evidence that he is willing to solve the task himself.

Comment: I don't get the date format. "26/08/2011" implies "dd/MM/yyyy" but 10/08/2011 isn't the first week of August 2011.

Comment: @Tunaki but it is less than 7 days after August 6th; I think that is what "week 1" is meant to mean. Not especially clear, though.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to Date or Calendar and retreive the field you need

Assumming your Date is String this is what you must do to convert it to Date and Calendar

```
String startDate =  "06/08/2011 00:00:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
Date startDateasDate = format.parse(startDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDateasDate);
```

Then you can retrieve wichever date you want with the proper flag:

```
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int weekOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Here you can see a list of the available flags:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: can you show some code how you do this? your answer looks like the right solution but is not a really helpful answer yet!

Comment: You're right. Alread edited. Hope it helps

Comment: very nice answer now!

Comment: @Martin Frank I have update my question with answer can you please help in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the start date, end date and input date to LocalDateTime
2. Check that the entered date is after the start date and before the end date. You can use LocalDateTime.isBefore and isAfter for this.
3. Use LocalDateTime.until with TemporalUnit set to weeks to calculate the amount of weeks from the start date to the entered date. You can then add 1 to this result to get the week number (0 amount of weeks = week 1, 1 amount of weeks = week 2 and so on)

Comment: From my example if it is 10/08/2011 it has to show week no as 1,if it is 25/08/2011 it has to show week no 3. According LocalDateTime.isBefore and isAfter it check if entered date  is before and after date and return 1. right?

Comment: Yeah, my understanding of the first version of your question was that entered date must fall between start and end date. If this is not the case, then you do not need end date for the calculation. You would still want to check that the entered date is greater than the start date though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but i should not use Until API,so i used my own code in it can you help me in optimizing it